# syntax-highlighting strings incorrectly for strings in opascal-mode

Tags: major-mode, syntax-highlighting, string

I write my projects in *FreePascal* and use `opascal-mode` to write it. I'm having a problem that this mode thinks that `'\'` is not a complete string, and hence all code after it is highlighted as a string.
**How can I change the opascal-mode (or add a hook) in which it will not try to parse the backslash as an escape character?** In FreePascal, strings do not support backslash as an escape char.

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 and this is a sample code that when run in opascal-mode, it highlights everything after the `'\'` improperly:

```
// syntax_highlight.dpr                                                                                                                                                                                                

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
program my_program;
uses Classes;

var newVal : char;

begin
  newVal := '\'; // syntax highlight breaks here!                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  if newVal = '''' then begin                                                                                                                                                                                          
    writeln('single quote');                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  end else if newVal = '\' then begin
    writeln('backslash');
  end;
end.
```

I've tried messing around with `modify-syntax-entry`, but nothing I tried worked.

---

EDIT: this is the fixed config in `~/.emacs` after I've implemented @JeanPierre's fix

```
;; associate pascal files as opascal-mode                                                                                                                                                              
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pas$" . opascal-mode))
(let* ((pascal-files '(".pas" ".pp" ".inc" ".lpr" ".dpr"))
       (pascal-regexp (concat (regexp-opt pascal-files t) "\\'")))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons pascal-regexp 'opascal-mode)))

;; don't escape backslashes in pascal    
(add-hook 'opascal-mode-hook
          (modify-syntax-entry ?\\ "."))
```

Comment: This would be a font-lock issue rather than syntax-table one. I don't know how the highlighting implemented in this mode, but I'd look for the mode's source: the font-lock rules would be the place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-h s` (`describe-syntax`) shows that `\` indeed has *escape* syntax.  You can change it with the following:

```el
(defun my/make-backslash-punctuation ()
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\\ "."))

(add-hook 'opascal-mode-hook #'my/make-backslash-punctuation)
```

Comment: that's perfect! it worked like a charm. Thanks!